# Editing Android diary entries

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Just a quick question, I'm creating an Android diary application, where the main page consists of three buttons: "New" to create a new entry, "All" to view all entries from the database, and "Search" to search entries matching some piece of text.

When I click on "All", it takes me to a new Intent which displays all entries in a ListView. However, when I click on a cell, it takes me back to the intent that "New" would direct me to, but instead of being able to edit the entry, it just displays blank fields, which if I enter, just creates another entry in the ListView. Would anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this? The code is as follows:

./Diary Main for the main page

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class DiaryMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button showEntries, newEntry, searchEntries;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary_main);

        showEntries = findViewById(R.id.displayAllBtn);
        newEntry = findViewById(R.id.newEntryBtn);
        searchEntries = findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);

        loadFromDBToMemory();

    }


    public void displayEntries(View view) {
        Intent btnClick = new Intent(this, DiaplayAllEntries.class);
        startActivity(btnClick);
    }

    public void newEntry(View view) {
        Intent btnClick = new Intent(this, NoteDetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(btnClick);
    }

    public void searchEntries(View view) {
        Intent btnClick = new Intent(this, SearchEntries.class);
        startActivity(btnClick);
    }

    private void loadFromDBToMemory() {
        SecondDataBaseHelper secondDataBaseHelper = SecondDataBaseHelper.databaseInstance(this);

        secondDataBaseHelper.populateDiaryListArray();
    }

}
```

./NoteDetailActivity, where the user can add a new diary entry:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class NoteDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editID, editSubject, editContent, editDate, editLatitude, editLongitude;
    private Diary selectedDiary;
    SecondDataBaseHelper secondDataBaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_detail);

        editID = findViewById(R.id.IDEditText);
        editSubject = findViewById(R.id.SubjectEditText);
        editContent = findViewById(R.id.contentEditText);
        editDate = findViewById(R.id.dateEditText);
        editLatitude = findViewById(R.id.latitudeEditText);
        editLongitude = findViewById(R.id.longitudeEditText);

        checkForEdit();
    }

    private void checkForEdit() {
        Intent previousIntent = getIntent();

        int passedDiaryID = previousIntent.getIntExtra(Diary.DIARY_EDIT_EXTRA, -1);

        selectedDiary = Diary.getDiaryForID(passedDiaryID);

        if (selectedDiary != null) {
            editID.setText(selectedDiary.getId());
            editSubject.setText(selectedDiary.getSubject());
            editContent.setText(selectedDiary.getContent());
            editDate.setText(selectedDiary.getDate());
            editLatitude.setText(selectedDiary.getLatitude());
            editLongitude.setText(selectedDiary.getLongitude());
         }
    }

    public void saveEntry(View view) {
        SecondDataBaseHelper secondDataBaseHelper = SecondDataBaseHelper.databaseInstance(this);
        String id = String.valueOf(editID.getText());
        String subject = String.valueOf(editSubject.getText());
        String content = String.valueOf(editContent.getText());
        String date = String.valueOf(editDate.getText());
        String latitude = String.valueOf(editLatitude.getText());
        String longitude = String.valueOf(editLongitude.getText());

        if (selectedDiary == null) {
            Diary newDiary = new Diary(id, subject, content, date, latitude, longitude);
            Diary.diaryArrayList.add(newDiary);
            secondDataBaseHelper.addEntryToDatabase(newDiary);
        } else {
            selectedDiary.setId(id);
            selectedDiary.setSubject(subject);
            selectedDiary.setContent(content);
            selectedDiary.setDate(date);

            secondDataBaseHelper.addEntryToDatabase(selectedDiary);
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

./DisplayAllEntries, where the user can see all of the diary entries, with each entry being a clickable ListView cell:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class DiaplayAllEntries extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView entryListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diaplay_all_entries);

        entryListView = findViewById(R.id.diaryListView);

        setDiaryAdapter();
        setOnClickListener();
    }



    private void setDiaryAdapter() {
        DiaryAdapter diaryAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Diary.diaryArrayList);
        entryListView.setAdapter(diaryAdapter);
    }

    private void setOnClickListener() {
        entryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Diary selectedEntry = (Diary) entryListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent editNoteIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteDetailActivity.class);
                editNoteIntent.putExtra(Diary.DIARY_EDIT_EXTRA, selectedEntry.getId());
                startActivity(editNoteIntent);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

./Diary, which is the information for the individual diary entry, with getters/setters/etc.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Diary {
    private String id;
    private String subject;
    private String content;
    private String date;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    public static ArrayList<Diary> diaryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static String DIARY_EDIT_EXTRA = "diaryEdit";

    public Diary(String id, String subject, String content, String date, String latitude, String longitude) {
        this.id = id;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.content = content;
        this.date = date;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public static Diary getDiaryForID(int passedDiaryID) {
        for (Diary diary : diaryArrayList) {
            if (Integer.parseInt((diary.getId())) == passedDiaryID) {
                return diary;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

./SecondDataBaseHelper is the database for the project:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SecondDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static SecondDataBaseHelper secondDataBaseHelper;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    public final static String DATABASE_NM ="RECORD_OF_USER";
    public final static String TABLE_NM ="DATA_OF_USER";
    public final static String COL_1 = "ID";
    public final static String COL_2 = "SUBJECT";
    public final static String COL_3 = "ENTRY";
    public final static String COL_4 = "DATE";
    public final static String COL_5 = "LATITUDE";
    public final static String COL_6 = "LONGITUDE";


    public SecondDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NM, null, 1);
    }

    public static SecondDataBaseHelper databaseInstance(Context context) {
        if (secondDataBaseHelper == null) {
            secondDataBaseHelper = new SecondDataBaseHelper(context);
        }

        return secondDataBaseHelper;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NM +" (ID TEXT, SUBJECT TEXT, ENTRY TEXT, DATE TEXT, LATITUDE TEXT, LONGITUDE TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void addEntryToDatabase(Diary entry) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(COL_1, entry.getId());
        contentValues.put(COL_2, entry.getSubject());
        contentValues.put(COL_3, entry.getContent());
        contentValues.put(COL_4, entry.getDate());
        contentValues.put(COL_5, entry.getLatitude());
        contentValues.put(COL_6, entry.getLongitude());

        db.insert(TABLE_NM, null, contentValues);
    }

    public void populateDiaryListArray() {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();

        try (Cursor result = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NM, null)) {
            if (result.getCount() != 0) {
                while (result.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = result.getString(1);
                    String subject = result.getString(2);
                    String content = result.getString(3);
                    String date = result.getString(4);
                    String latitude = result.getString(5);
                    String longitude = result.getString(6);

                    Diary diary = new Diary(id, subject, content, date, latitude, longitude);
                    Diary.diaryArrayList.add(diary);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void updateDiaryInDB(Diary entry) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(COL_1, entry.getId());
        contentValues.put(COL_2, entry.getSubject());
        contentValues.put(COL_3, entry.getContent());
        contentValues.put(COL_4, entry.getDate());
        contentValues.put(COL_5, entry.getLatitude());
        contentValues.put(COL_6, entry.getLongitude());

        sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NM, contentValues, COL_1 + " ?= ", new String[]{String.valueOf(entry.getId())});
    }
}
```

Debugging everything, I believe the issue is either the .onItemClick() in ./DisplayAllEntries, or the checkForEdit() in ./NoteDetailActivity. Conversely, this might be a bad schema overall, so if anyone has any ideas for how to be able to click the individual cells for editing, I'd be super appreciative!

Comment: `editNoteIntent.putExtra(Diary.DIARY_EDIT_EXTRA, selectedEntry.getId());` – Your `Diary#getId()` method returns a `String`, so you're putting a `String` extra on the `Intent` there. However, in `NoteDetailActivity`, you're checking for an `int` extra: `int passedDiaryID = previousIntent.getIntExtra(Diary.DIARY_EDIT_EXTRA, -1);`. Probably makes more sense to handle the ID as a number everywhere.

Comment: ...I'm between laughing and crying, as that's exactly what I needed. Haha, much appreciation from a newbie. On a similar note, I need to use the Google Maps API to display a map based on the latitude/longitude input strings. I'll have to reimplement those as doubles in the app, but if I add a "Map" button in that "All" intent which displays all the diary entries, would I follow something similar, wherein once I clicked "Map", I could automatically feed in those lat/lon coordinates into a new intent that submitted them to the API and returned an ImageView?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean, there. Are you asking if starting an `Intent` with extras is the right way to get a map of a specific location? Or are you asking specifically how to get an `ImageView` instead of a `MapView`? Or maybe something else entirely?

Comment: Sorry for the vague question, but yes, I believe the first is what I am looking for advice on.

Comment: In that case, maybe? It depends on what you mean to do, specifically. If you want to start yet another `Activity` that contains the actual map, then yeah, you could use that same mechanism to pass the coordinates to that next `Activity`, and then retrieve them there and hand them to a `MapView` (which is the base UI component for the Maps API, btw). If instead you just want to pop up a small dialog or window within the same `Activity`, you wouldn't need to mess with the `Intent` at all, though there would obviously be some other setup involved. Make sense?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, that's great info, thank you. Yeah, ideally when the user goes to the view/edit intent, there would be a "Map" button at the top toolbar, and I envisioned it just going to a new Intent and displaying the map (and weather info from where the post was created; I have to figure out how to get that from the NWS site tomorrow). But if it could just display as a popup, I would just want to use a Fragment for that, correct?

Comment: Sure, a `Fragment` is an option, and there are a few base classes designed to be "pop-ups" that might make sense for your design; e.g., `DialogFragment`, `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, etc. You could also somehow integrate the `MapView` into the `Activity`'s content; e.g., as a drawer directly in the main layout, or maybe as a bottom sheet there, etc. You'll get a better feel for what would be appropriate for a given setup as you go.

Comment: Hey, that's some really great information. I think DialogFragment might be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks again for the great advice!

Answer (score 0):

`Diary`s id is `String`

```
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

and you are passing this value in `Bundle`s extra:

```
editNoteIntent.putExtra(Diary.DIARY_EDIT_EXTRA, selectedEntry.getId());
```

but in `NoteDetailActivity` you are trying to read it as `Integer`

```
int passedDiaryID = previousIntent.getIntExtra(Diary.DIARY_EDIT_EXTRA, -1);
```

you should use `getStringExtra` method in here, eventually if you need it as `int` the use `Integer.parseInt(...)`